# Terracotta cluster in open source

Tags: terracotta

I want to store cache data in `terracotta` server array.

For high availability and scalability I want to form cluster. So, whether it is possible to form `terracotta` cluster in open source or else I should go for `terracotta` enterprise edition ?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I work for Terracotta (Software AG)*

Since earlier this month, [Terracotta 4.3](http://terracotta.org/downloads/open-source/catalog) offers an open source version.
See the following [blog post](http://blog.terracotta.org/2015/04/02/terracotta-bolsters-in-memory-open-source-offerings/) for the announcement.

The open source version offers unlimited memory storage but on a single server stripe, which can have high availability through the use of passive servers.

There are also no limits on the number of clients that can be connected.

Comment: Does it supports java 8? What is the difference (for developer) between 3.7.5 and 4.4? Any docs for migraion?